# Angular/YouTube API v3: 401 Invalid credentials error on search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, youtube, youtube-api

Still learning Angular, so be gentle please. ;)

I was successfully getting search results when I first created and added a YouTube API key. However, the next day it stopped working and gives me a 401 error with a message "Invalid credentials".

I've seen a few questions on here about having to add OAuth, but I don't think that applies to me, since I'm only searching and playing videos... right?

I've been using [this project](https://github.com/jgthms/juketube) as a guide, and it works just fine. I'm not sure what I've done differently.

Here's my controller with the `$http.get` to search.

```
var youtubeAPIKey = "AIzaSyA4EF_e56jFBfRPBx57wkzN2ppKudMcZvk";

$scope.search = function() {
  $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
    params: {
      key: youtubeAPIKey,
      type: 'video',
      maxResults: '20',
      part: 'id,snippet',
      videoCategoryId: '10',
      q: this.query
    }
  })
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.searchResults = data;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Not sure if it matters, but here's the search HTML

```
<div class="search-box">
  <form ng-submit="search()">
    <input type="search" placeholder="It's your turn! Search for a song to add"
    ng-model="query" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="search-results" ng-if="searchResults">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-item"
      ng-repeat="result in searchResults.items" 
      ng-click="add(result.id.videoId, result.snippet.title)">
      <div class="song-info">{{result.snippet.title}}</div>
      <button class="player-btn glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"
        ng-click="preview(result.id.videoId, result.snippet.title)">   
      </button>
      <button class="player-btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Here's the error:

```
error: Object
  code: 401
  errors: Array[1]
    0: Object
    domain: "global"
    location: "Authorization"
    locationType: "header"
    message: "Invalid Credentials"
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I would first check you can actually make the request via a RESTful console (such as [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)), CURL or simply from the browser. For example, run from the command line:

```
$ curl -XGET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=<API_KEY_HERE>\&part=id,snippet
```

or simply from the browser:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=<API_KEY_HERE>&part=id,snippet
```

That will at least isolate whether the problem is with angular or with the endpoint/request.

Comment: I'm able to get results back using the URL you posted, but if I try to add a query or category, such as this: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyA4EF_e56jFBfRPBx57wkzN2ppKudMcZvk&part=id,snippet&q=kanye` I get a 403 error with a message of `There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.`

Comment: Also, I don't have an HTTP referrer set. I tried to add OAuth to it, but I got the same "Invalid credentials" error.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't setup a proper Youtube API key (it looks like you need one). I would suggest setting one up and making the same request with the new API key and see if you can get past the error .